# How to use LIST_AGG in netsuite

Tags: sql, netsuite

I want to concatenate the result of a column in `Netsuite`. I tried `List_Agg` but no luck.

```
select t.id, LIST_AGG(tn.trackingnumber, ',')
from transaction t
left join trackingnumber tn on
            (
            INSTR(', '||t.trackingnumberlist||', ', ', '||tn.id||', ') > 0
            )
where t.id = 1
```

Here `t.trackingnumberlist` = 1,2,3

Any suggestion/alternate of `LIST_AGG`

Answer (score 1):

I've spoken with NetSuite support about this in the past, and unfortunately, it is not possible. Their ODBC SuiteAnalytics Connect service is based on the SQL-92 standard, rather than any Oracle database standard, thus it does not have this feature, as LIST_AGG was added to Oracle SQL back in 11g in 2007 (14 years ago - https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques#listagg).

I've had to resort to performing my own aggregate functions within my C# code after pulling the data over, as SQL-92 is so limited, that it's not possible to even reproduce the function of what LIST_AGG does in that environment.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about SuiteAnalytics Connect, but I can run the following query in SuiteScript using the `N/query.runSuiteQL()` function. This is in Netsuite 2022.1.

```sql
SELECT
    LISTAGG (tranid, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY tranid) AS document_numbers,
    trandate AS date
FROM
    transaction
WHERE
    rownum < 10
GROUP BY trandate
```

It does appear that there is a character limit for each result, so if you are seeing errors, you might try reducing the number of results you are aggregating.